# Tensorflow RNN stuck at 20% error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I created my first tensorflow neuronal network, initially for generating sequences. It produced weird outputs so I simplified it a lot to see if it can reach an error rate of 0% with just 5 inputs and 5 output classes.
   Somehow it does not seem to backpropagate at all because it is stuck at 20 % error rate without moving at all. So if anyone can point me to my mistake I made thank you in advance :)

Cheers

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

trainingInputs = [
[[0],[0],[0],[0]],
[[1],[0],[0],[0]],
[[0],[1],[0],[0]],
[[0],[0],[1],[0]],
[[0],[0],[0],[1]]]
trainingOutputs = [
[1,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0]]

data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(trainingInputs[0]),1])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(trainingOutputs[0])])
num_hidden = 24
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)
val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)
val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, int(target.get_shape()[1])]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[target.get_shape()[1]]))
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(prediction,1e-10,1.0)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
mistakes = tf.not_equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

batch_size = 1
no_of_batches = int((len(trainingInputs)) / batch_size)

def trainNetwork():
    epoch = 1000
    for i in range(epoch):
        ptr = 0
        for j in range(no_of_batches):
            inp, out = trainingInputs[ptr:ptr+batch_size], trainingOutputs[ptr:ptr+batch_size]
            ptr+=batch_size
            sess.run(minimize, feed_dict={data: inp, target: out})


def generateOutput():
    incorrect = sess.run(error,{data: trainingInputs, target: trainingOutputs})
    sys.stdout.write('error {:3.1f}%'.format(100 * incorrect) + "\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()

for i in range(200):
    trainNetwork()
    generateOutput()

sess.close()
```

Comment: Can you print the cross-entropy and see if it's getting minimized?

Comment: well It produces floats like this : 1.3862943649291992
1.4553226232528687
1.356396198272705
1.4721133708953857
-0.0
1.3892346620559692
1.4517250061035156
1.3586615324020386
1.4662749767303467
-0.0
1.3917416334152222
1.4484480619430542
1.3607909679412842
1.4607824087142944
-0.0

Comment: can you put Tensorboard graphs ?